# How to make a bunch of planes in blender move like wind but stay where they are?

Tags: animation

I want all these planes to move like they are big and being hit by wind without flying everywhere, they are supposed to be attached to each other. Basically really big pieces of paper in the air that are affected by the wind but still stay where they are. I tried adding wind to one plane and mess around with it and I also asked ChatGPT and it said something about clothing but it didn't work.[image: The model I want to animate] Here's a video about what I wanna make (spoiler for alice in borderland s2e1) https://www.mediafire.com/file/jmstesq6d72hqm5/What+I+want+to+create.mp4/file

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by 'not flying everywhere' in this context. Should all the planes be deformed as if a single piece, invisibly connected? Do you want ripples to flow through the whole object, wile it stays in the same place, in shot?

Comment: pls add a link to a video how it should look like so it is crystal clear how you want it to be, thx

Comment: I was thinking about showing you guys but the think is it will be like a spoiler

Comment: I hit enter to make a new line not comment, does shift+enter work?
Yes
I don't wanna spoil but I will post a link with a spoiler-wall when I have time to show exactly what I mean.

Comment: HERE'S WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE (spoilers for Alice in Borderland s2e1) https://www.mediafire.com/file/jmstesq6d72hqm5/What+I+want+to+create.mp4/file